# How to detect my application is idle in c# (form covered)?

Tags: c#, detect

I have this problem today, i saw this solution:

[How to detect my application is idle in c#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5882658/how-to-detect-my-application-is-idle-in-c)

I tried that, but my form is covered with userControls and other elements, and the mouseover or keydown events are only fired in the margins of those elements.

Is there a better way?

Comment: Yes there is, can we show you? no we cant, why? because you havent shown us code that you have tried that we can improve on :)

Comment: Did you try looking at the [links in this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5883435/479512) to your linked question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hacking together a solution with timers and mouse events is unnecessary. Just handle the Application.Idle event.

```
Application.Idle += Application_Idle;

private void Application_Idle(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //    The application is now idle.
}
```

Comment: But then you have to hack together something to show that the user is not idle :D

Answer (score 1):

If you want a more dynamic approach you could subscribe to all of the events in your `Form` because ultimately if a user is idle no events should ever be raised.

```
private void HookEvents()
{
    foreach (EventInfo e in GetType().GetEvents())
    {
        MethodInfo method = GetType().GetMethod("HandleEvent", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
        Delegate provider = Delegate.CreateDelegate(e.EventHandlerType, this, method);
        e.AddEventHandler(this, provider);
    }
}

private void HandleEvent(object sender, EventArgs eventArgs)
{
    lastInteraction = DateTime.Now;
}
```

You could declare a global variable `private DateTime lastInteraction = DateTime.Now;` and assign to it from the event handler. You could then write a simple property to determine how many seconds have elapsed since the last user interaction.

```
private TimeSpan LastInteraction
{
    get { return DateTime.Now - lastInteraction; }
}
```

And then poll the property with a `Timer` as described in the original solution.

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   if (LastInteraction.TotalSeconds > 90)
   {
       MessageBox.Show("Idle!", "Come Back! I need You!");
   }
}
```