# automatic close not used form?

Tags: c#

how can i catch when the form not used by the user 
i need to make form that will closed after 5 minutes if the user don't make any action on this form  with C# Code Please help me

I make this code for closing system after 5 minutes

```
        Timer.Interval = (1000) * (300); 
        Timer.Enabled = true;
        Timer.Start();  

 private void Timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Close(); 
        }
```

But i need to make this code active if the form not used .

Comment: it might help you [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5882658/how-to-detect-my-application-is-idle-in-c)

Comment: Add Timer.Start in your Forms LostFocus Event and in the Timer_Tick event calculate the time, if you find the time has exceeded 5 minutes close the form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the "Leave" event to manage your exit logic, like say trigger the timer.. The leave event gets fired on loosing focus.

Comment: thank you for your answer, but I don't mean when the form loses focus and is no longer the active form. I mean if the form stile on focus but not used by the system user

Comment: @ahmedmohamady then how do you mean "not used by user"? You say, the form is active and there is no activity on the system? like no keyboard/mouse activity?

Comment: you know the screen server method?
I need some thing like this but the event will be closing the form

Comment: you may read thru [link](http://www.harding.edu/fmccown/screensaver/screensaver.html) or [link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4809/How-to-develop-a-screen-saver-in-C) for ideas

Answer (score 0):

write this.

```
    private void Form1_Activated(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Timer.Enabled = false;
    }

    private void Form1_Deactivate(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Timer.Enabled = true;
    }
```

Comment: Good, but what if form is active one, but I don't click it or move mouse over it?

Comment: thank you for your answer, but I don't mean when the form loses focus and is no longer the active form.
I mean if the form stile on focus but not used by the system user