# Close form after idle period

Tags: c#

I have a simple application, I want to close it if the user does nothing in 10 minutes. 
I try use timer and stopwatch but I can't solve it.

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern Boolean GetLastInputInfo(ref tagLASTINPUTINFO plii);

public struct tagLASTINPUTINFO
{
    public uint cbSize;
    public Int32 dwTime;
}

private void counter_idle_time_step2_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    tagLASTINPUTINFO LastInput = new tagLASTINPUTINFO();
    Int32 IdleTime;
    LastInput.cbSize = (uint)Marshal.SizeOf(LastInput);
    LastInput.dwTime = 0;

    if (GetLastInputInfo(ref LastInput))
    {
        IdleTime = System.Environment.TickCount - LastInput.dwTime;
        if (lg_st2.counter_time_logout == (IdleTime / 1000))
        {
            this.Close();
            lg_st2.Show();
        }
    }
}
```

How can I do it. Please show me some sample for this.

Comment: Maybe [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1542089/1277156) can help you. The timer tick function is where you can change the time to your 10 minutes.

Comment: `I try use timer and stopwatch but I can't solve it.`: okay, so what happens with the code you have up there now? It seems pretty straight forward to me.

Comment: Maybe instead of `==` you want `>=`?

Comment: Make that <= instead.

Answer (score 0):

I dont understand much of your code, but one thing I see is that line:

```
if (lg_st2.counter_time_logout == (IdleTime / 1000))
```

In the moment you just say: If did nothing for exactly 10 Minutes, then close. (If it´s 10 min and 1 sec, it wont work)
But, what you want to say is that:

```
if (lg_st2.counter_time_logout <= (IdleTime / 1000))
```

With this line It should work.
Sorry if it doesn´t.

Greetings
Björn