# How to get mouse move events in a main form when child controls have focus

Tags: c#, winforms, mouseevent, childcontrol

I have a winforms application whose UI is designed as multi layer of user controls. I am adding code changes to monitor if my application is idle for a certain amount of time. For that I am monitoring keyboard and mouse events in my base form. Keyboard events are received even when child control is in focus where as mouse events are not received in the base form.
Note - child controls covers almost entire main form's area.

approaches which did not work:

1. I have tried to capture WM_MOUSEMOVE, WM_LBUTTONDOWN in WndProc() of main form. these messages are not captured when mouse is moved on child control
2. Hooked to MouseMove, MouseClick, KeyDown events in mainform, set KeyPreview and Captrure to true
   by this, only key events are received, mouse events are not received when child control is in focus
3. Do not want to use system hooks as it comes with serious security issues

Can somebody tell me what is the easy way to get mouse move events in the main form when child control has the focus? I do not want to make changes in each  of the child control as many of them do not inherit from a single base user control class

Comment: See [How to detect a Winforms app has been idle for certain amount of time](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36430850/719186)

Comment: You can implement IMessageFilter on the parent Form. The Form will receive all messages directed to child Controls before they reach the intended recipient. See the example here: [Handle MouseMove, MouseDown, MouseUp Events in a ListView to drag a borderless Form](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71143588/7444103). You can of course handle any other message (`WM_KEYDOWN`, for example)

Answer (score 1):

Capture the event on the parent form using a normal event handler then in the form constructor add the following code

```
foreach (Control control in this.Controls)
{
    control.MouseMove += Form1_MouseMove; //where Form1_MouseMove is the name of the event handler
}
```

if you want to make sure you also capture events in controls that will be added later add the following code

```
private void Form1_ControlAdded(object sender, ControlEventArgs e)
{
    e.Control.MouseMove += Form1_MouseMove;
}
```

and attach it to the Form.ControlAdded event

See the full example below

```
namespace mouse_capture_example
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        int moveCount = 0;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            //capture MouseMove event for all controls
            foreach (Control control in this.Controls)
            {
                control.MouseMove += Form1_MouseMove;
            }
        }

        private void Form1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            moveCount++;
            Console.WriteLine($"The mouse has been moved {moveCount} times");
        }
        
        //capture mouse events for controls being added later
        private void Form1_ControlAdded(object sender, ControlEventArgs e)
        {
            e.Control.MouseMove += Form1_MouseMove;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this is very helpful.. but in my application it is not just 2 level where you will have a parent form and then controls are added. I have multilevel of forms and controls. e.g, form then a control then multiple controls over that control and few more levels controls in a similar way.. how to hook the events from all these levels to parent form

Comment: @AnushaAladakatti are you working with custom controls?

Comment: No, winforms and generic UserControls